# How to display image in UIImageView like original image?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am having a UIImageView with size 320*110.1x and 2x images seems to work good but when it comes to 3x the image looks squashed.How to display image in UIImageView like original image without stretching? Moreover the UI looks different in different devices. I am using ScaleToFill content mode here. I have tried aspectFit but it comes with blank spaces in left and right of the UIImageView and image does not fits in AspectFill.Is it possible to display image like original image in all devices without stretching? Please look at the screenshots of what I have tried.

Original 3x Image:
[image]

iPhone 6 plus:

[image]

iPhone 7 Plus:
[image]

Comment: What is the desired outcome?

Comment: Yes. In your storyboard, find the perfect size for you image, then apply two Constraints: "Equal Width" and "Equal Height" to superview, and then change the multiplier to `0.yourValue` to both, and the image view and the image will both fit perfectly

Comment: You can compute height for desired width and set it for your imageview. This way your aspect ratio will be kept.

Comment: Or just set aspect ratio to self instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your images, it appears that you have set the height of your `UIImageView` to be `110` points.  Instead, you need the height to grow as the width grows.

Pin the top, leading, and trailing edges of your `UIImageView` to its superview.  Finally, set the height of your `UIImageView` by creating an *Aspect Ratio* constraint that sets the `image.width` *Equal To* `image.height` with a *multiplier* of `320:110`.  You can do this by <kbd>control</kbd>-clicking in your `UIImageView` and dragging up and to the right and then releasing while still inside of your image view.  Then choose *Aspect Ratio* from the pop-up.  In the *Attributes Inspector* change the multiplier for the constraint to `320:110`.

[image: Aspect Ratio constraint in Attributes Inspector]

As you indicated in your question, set the *Content Mode* of your `UIImageView` to *Scale To Fill*.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the contentMode of the uiimageview to aspectfit